# Orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these vectors:

$B = (u, v, w)$ with $u = (9, 1, x)$, $v = (0, x, 9)$ and $w = (-1, 9, 0)$.

The first question wants to find every $x$ so that $B$ is NOT a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For this i found that $x = \sqrt{738}$

The second question asks to find every $x$ so  that $b$ is an orthogonal basis. 
I found that $x = 0$.

I am stuck on the third question that asks to make an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the help of $B$

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can do it with the help of Gram–Schmidt algorithm.

Comment: Actually, you're almost done: consider the vectors $u', v'$ and $w'$ given by $u'=u/\Vert u\Vert$ and so on with $x=0$. Since the basis $\{u, v, w\}$ is orthogonal, the basis $\{u', v', w'\}$ is orthonormal.

Answer (score 2):

1. $B$ is *not* a Basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ *iff* $\det B=0$
   $$\det B \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Longleftrightarrow -737 - \left(9-x^2\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow x\pm \sqrt{746}$$
2. $x=0$ is correct
3. Just chose $u' = \frac{u}{\|u\|}$ and so on, then...